# Convergent of series,using cauchy root test

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to check convergence of the seris:
$$\sum \left(\frac{n - \log(n)}{2^n n^n}\right)^n$$
I have only figure out that I have to apply, Cauchy root test.But after taking limit, I am totally blank, please help

Comment: ?? For $n\geqslant2$, $$\frac{n - \log(n)}{2^n n^n}\leqslant\frac{n}{ 2^2n^2}=\frac1{4n}$$ hence $$\left(\frac{n - \log(n)}{2^n n^n}\right)^n\leqslant\left(\frac{n - \log(n)}{2^n n^n}\right)^2\leqslant\frac1{16n^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $\log n<n$,

$$0<\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{n-\log n}{2^nn^n}\right)^n}=\frac{n-\log n}{2^nn^n}\le\frac1{2^nn^{n-1}}\to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the root test you get
$$\limsup_n \Big| \frac{n-\log n}{2^n n^n}\Big|=\lim_n \frac{n-\log n}{2^nn^n}=0$$
so the series converges.